# Java multithreading: redundant to use java.util.concurrent classes in a synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class with the following class level variables:

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> inputQueue;
private StringBuffer textBuffer;
private int currentIndex;
private String[] p;
private List<String[]> pageList;
private int cursor;
```

The class has a method setInput() that could be accessed by multiple threads. The method changes all the above variables like this

```
public void setInput(String s) {
    p[cursor] = input;
    cursor++;
    if (cursor == 1000) {
        // UI logic
        textBuffer.setLength(0);
        p = new String[];
        cursor = 0;
    }
    // Some other logic here

    pageList.add(p);
    currentIndex++;
    if (!inputQueue.offer(currentIndex)) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }        
}
```

These variables can be read by other code snippet in the class, but they are only modified in setInput(). And all the other methods in the class do not have thread safety issue. In other words, they are ensured to be called by the main thread. In this scenario, if I put synchronized keyword before method setInput(), then do I need to use the LinkedBlockingQueue from java.util.concurrent? Are those variables guaranteed to be thread safe when the method is synchronized? Thanks.

Comment: Please use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer as it was replace ten years ago. It is near impossible to use StringBuffer correctly without external synchronization.

Comment: What code is pulling data out of inputQueue?  That would affect if it needed to be concurrent or not.

Comment: Thank you for the point. Yes the poll operation is done in the main thread, not in this method. So a concurrent queue is required here. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you put an int in the queue, instead of your class?  Have you considered creating a new YourClass each time (perhaps immutable) and putting them in the queue?  (Which must be declared as static or outside of your class)   That's how I typically use Queues.  But obviously I dont understand your app and requirements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in your scenario making the `setInput` method `synchronized` is not enough. *All* methods accessing the variables need to be synchronized, also the methods which only read the variables, otherwise the variables might be read while `setInput` is executing and thus you might see an inconsistent state of the object.

If a lot of threads are reading the variables but only a few are writing them, making the reading methods also `synchronized` might be an unnecessary performance bottleneck. In that case it is better to use a `ReadWriteLock`, so that all reading threads may access the object at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To be thread safe, all methods accessing the fields (reading and writing) should be `synchronized`